# Add two number without action button react.js (Auto update)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to add two number by taking default value in input field (num1=2 , num2=2). How can I add this two number without Add button. Like for example if user change the num1 value to 4 from 2 it should update the value  adding number 2 value ( num1= 4 + num2 =2 = result 6). It should auto update the the third input field value or text with result value in it.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: 0,
      num1: 2,
      num2: 2
    };

    this.handlenum1Change = this.handlenum1Change.bind(this);
    this.handlenum2Change = this.handlenum2Change.bind(this);
  }
  handlenum1Change(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
    this.setState({ num1: Number(evt.target.value) });
  }
  handlenum2Change(evt) {
    console.log(typeof evt.target.value);
    this.setState({ num2: Number(evt.target.value) });
  }
  addAction = event => {
    let x = this.state.num1 + this.state.num2;
    this.setState({ result: x });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="num1"
            value={this.state.num1}
            onChange={this.handlenum1Change}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name="num2"
            value={this.state.num2}
            onChange={this.handlenum2Change}
          />
          <input type="button" onClick={this.addAction} value="Add" />
          <input type="text" value={this.state.result} readOnly />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the value that changed with the value that didn't change and make it the new `result` when you update either one of the numbers.

**Example**

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    result: 4,
    num1: 2,
    num2: 2
  };

  handlenum1Change = evt => {
    const num1 = Number(evt.target.value);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      num1,
      result: num1 + prevState.num2
    }));
  };

  handlenum2Change = evt => {
    const num2 = Number(evt.target.value);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      num2,
      result: prevState.num1 + num2
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="num1"
            value={this.state.num1}
            onChange={this.handlenum1Change}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name="num2"
            value={this.state.num2}
            onChange={this.handlenum2Change}
          />
          <input type="text" value={this.state.result} readOnly />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```